# Ajax store response json in variables

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

The response of success ajax call is in the form of json like this one:

```
{"prize_name":"Keys 4","prize_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/web-game-w\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/4rare.jpg"}
```

How I can store "prize_name" & "prize_image" in variables for later use?

Here is the ajax code:

```
$("#ajax").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        'action': 'getprize_data',
        dataType: "json", 
        async: false
    };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // Store vars 
    });
});
```

Also I have an issue. This `response.prize_name` will return error `response.prize_name is undefined`.

Comment: declare two variable without using var before the ajax call and as sson as the reponse comes assign those values to those variables

Comment: @Gardezi How I can assign the values? I tried response.prize_name & response.prize_image. I always get undefined.

Comment: How are you returning your ajax request response  from the server @Yamona

Comment: It return as json and it look like this {"prize_name":"text","prize_image":"url"}

Comment: please console log your response if it's undefined then that means that you are no sending the values correctly from the server. I think you are using return keyword to return a JSON response if that's the problem then please return your json response like this `echo json_encode([]) `

Comment: do this `response = JSON.parse(reponse);`  and then try to retrieve the value

Comment: I did that 'echo json_encode([])' and get {"prize_name":"text","prize_image":"url"}

Comment: decode the reponse on the front end like this `response = JSON.parse(reponse);` and then retrieve the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155152/discussion-between-yamona-and-gardezi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare those variables without using var before the ajax call starts and assign the values to those variables in the success function

```
    prize_name = prize_image = ""; 
    $("#ajax").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST", 
          url: ajaxurl, // give url over here
          data: {action: 'getprize_data'}, 
          dataType: 'json', 
          async: false // always avoid false if you can
          success: function(response) { 
            console.log(response);
            response = JSON.parse(reponse);
            // Store vars 
            // assign the values over here 
            // maybe you will need to decode the json 
            // if you are encoding it so use JSON.parse
            // for decoding the json
          }, 

      });

    });
```

Now the reason why I'm saying to declare variable without using var is because

> If you don't use var , the variable bubbles up through the layers of
>   scope until it encounters a variable by the given name or the global
>   object (window, if you are doing it in the browser), where it then
>   attaches.

Answer (score 1):

Your [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) call is wrong. I'd suggest to avoid async to false. But, if you need at all cost such a behavious you can rewrite your post as:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: ajaxurl,
   data: {action: 'getprize_data'},
   success: function(response) {
             ......
            },
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false
 });
```

Instead to create global variables you can take advantage of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

You can store the values in this way:

```
$('#ajax').data('prizeName', response.prize_name);
```

And, in future, when you need such a value you can simply get the value with:

```
$('#ajax').data('prizeName');
```

Remember that ajax is asynchronous so the value will be available only when the succes callback will be executed. Hence, I suggest to use a callback function in your ajax success function.